# Problema con posicionamiento Navbar Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Tengo un problema al el contenido de los list items en mi navbar, la cosa es que cúando mi navbar esta desplegada en width ordenador se ve bien:

[image: Full width view]

El problema viene cúando lo hago responsive, y ya queda muy mal esa parte, debería ir abajo y no encogida en el mismo sitio, se que esta en el mismo div, pero si lo pongo en otro div me descuadra y la cosa es que tanto como el icono mas el usuario "jardeleanu " y el boton de log off estén siempre encima de los list items , tal y como esta en el full width , pero por la estructura que le he hecho eso no es posible cúando lo hago responsive, ya que se ve mal, y debería verse en vertical bien a full width debajo del logo...

Así se me ve en responsive:

[image: responsive view]

La cosa es que ami me gustaría que se vea así, sin mucho espacio verticcal entre los list item y el logo (en donde dice hamburguesa, va tambien el usuario y los iconos, en la misma linea claro está.

[image: Vista requerida]

Este es el código

```
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light mt-2 bg-white border-header-top justify-content-between">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://soporte.isyc.com/static/202004211417/theme/images/branding/portal_logo_core.png" /></a>
    <div>
        <div class="bg-green d-flex align-items-center mb-1 mb-lg-0 justify-content-end">
            <i class="mdi mdi-account-circle info pr-2 text-primary font-size-19"></i><a href="#" class="text-primary"><span class="pr-3 border-right border-primary font-size-14">jardeleanu</span></a><a href="/logout" class="pt-1"><i class="pl-3 pr-3 mdi mdi-power text-primary font-size-22"></i></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler border-primary no-outline" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i class="bi bi-list text-primary"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-secondary">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav text-primary flex-md-row" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item my-1 mx-1 mx-lg-2 font-size-md-13"><a href="#" class="text-primary d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mdi mdi-clipboard-file-outline font-size-14 pr-2"></i>CASOS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item my-1 mx-1 mx-lg-2 font-size-md-13"><a href="#" class="text-primary d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mdi mdi-timelapse font-size-14 pr-2"></i>IMPUTACIÓN HORAS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item my-1 mx-1 mx-lg-2 font-size-md-13"><a href="#" class="text-primary d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mdi mdi-timeline-check font-size-14 pr-2"></i>APROBACIÓN HORAS</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item my-1 mx-1 mx-lg-1 font-size-md-13"><a href="#" class="text-primary d-flex align-items-center"><i class="mdi mdi-tournament font-size-14 pr-2"></i></i>KANBAN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mejor de encerrar el toggle `<button>` en un div, coloca el div con los elementos que creaste, justo arriba del button, y colocale flex, de hecho lo puedes dejar como lo tienes, y luego tampoco encierres el div collapse navbar-collapse en un div, ese div que tiene como padre con clase bg-secondary lo puedes quitar.

Te edito mi primera respuesta:
Deja como te dije el div separado del button:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light h-100">

        <div class="container-fluid prueba">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <div class="bg-green d-flex mb-1 mb-lg-0 col-2 justify-content-end">
                <i class="mdi mdi-account-circle info pr-2 text-primary font-size-19"></i><a href="#" class="text-primary"><span class="pr-3 border-right border-primary font-size-14">jardeleanu</span></a><a href="/logout" class="pt-1"><i class="pl-3 pr-3 mdi mdi-power text-primary font-size-22"></i></a>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Te comento mejor:
Modifica las clases flex como las he colocado al div que lleva tu "hanburguesa"
Tambien modifica el flex del collapse, y luego tienes que hacer una modificación css al container, le he puesto la clase "pruebas" y el código es el siguiente:

```
.prueba{
   display: flex !important;
   flex-flow: wrap !important;
}
```

Espero te ayude

Saludos,

Comment: Hola Jose, no sirve, queda igual, muy mal estructurado, creo que debe ser problema de la estructura, yo lo que quiero es que esos iconos siempre queden fuera del collapse, y que queden al lado horizontalmente del boton collapse ( eso lo puedo hacer poniendo en el mismo div , un d-flex y alineando para que queden alineados verticalmente) el problema es que no se como hacer para que el collapse se vea en 100% width y no comparta espacio con los botones, que se vea abajo del logo y no al lado , como pasa ahora

Comment: Te edite mi primera respuesta

Comment: Hola Jose, me sigue quedando separado, la idea es que quede así en full width: 
https://ibb.co/k9YTfsQ

Comment: Creo que se ve bastante parecido: [https://ibb.co/V2zr0C0](https://ibb.co/V2zr0C0) y en responsive se ve el collapse full-width que ya lo puedes adaptar como quieras: [https://ibb.co/51KZZq3](https://ibb.co/51KZZq3)

Comment: Esperando a la respuesta del OP, o necesita mas arreglos ?? Por que lo solicitado se ha hecho, solo son un par de estilos para que quede igual.

Comment: Ami se me ve mal, con ese código :/

Comment: Actualiza como se vee amigo